# Unity C# JSONUtility doesn't put value in JSON string

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I've been looking, and trying to solve this myself, but just am not seeing it. I'm new to C#, and this is my first brush with JSON. I put in the following code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class IFScriptPlayerName : MonoBehaviour

{

    [Serializable]
    public class MyClass
    {
        //public int level;
        //public float timeElapsed;
        //public string playerName;
        //public InputField PlayerName;
        //public InputField CharName;
        //public InputField CharRank;

   [SerializeField] private string PlayerName;
    public string playerName {  get { return this.playerName; }
                       set { this.playerName = value; } }

    }

    MyClass myObject = new MyClass();

    public string playerName;


    public string SaveToString()
    {
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(myObject);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        var input = gameObject.GetComponent<InputField>();
        var se = new InputField.SubmitEvent();
        //se.AddListener(SubmitName);
        //input.onEndEdit = se;

        //or simply use the line below, 
        input.onEndEdit.AddListener(SubmitName);  // This also works
    }

    private void SubmitName(string playerName)
    {
        //Debug.Log(arg0);
    Debug.Log("Entered" + playerName);

    //playerName = arg0;
    Debug.Log ("Start SubmitName!" + SaveToString());

    StartCoroutine(Post("https://mywebsite.com/api/api2.php", SaveToString()));
    }

    IEnumerator Post(string url, string bodyJsonString)
    {
        var request = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST");
        byte[] bodyRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bodyJsonString);
        request.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler) new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
        request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler) new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        yield return request.Send();

        Debug.Log("Status Code: " + request.responseCode);
    Debug.Log("Received: " + request.downloadHandler.text);
    Debug.Log("json string: " + SaveToString());
    }
}
```

and the debug log shows: `json string: {"PlayerName":""}`
when I should be getting `json string: {"PlayerName":"MarkNoBerg"}`

What am I not doing right? I've tried just about everything I could think of, I see that the value I type in is getting to the debug log, just not getting to the value I need it to be.

Comment: you have two playerNames defined and one private? PlayerName, this is your problem.

Comment: And where are you assigning the `myObject.PlayerName = ...` ? Also .. I guess your property should rather get and set `PlayerName` right? Currently it is implemented recursively returning and setting itself ....

Comment: right you have playerName and PlayerName, and you never assign to PlayerName

Answer (score 0):

I think this might just be a case of tidying up MyClass and also assigning the variable to the class?

```
public class IFScriptPlayerName : MonoBehaviour

{

    [Serializable]
    public class MyClass
    {
        //public int level;
        //public float timeElapsed;
        //public string playerName;
        //public InputField PlayerName;
        //public InputField CharName;
        //public InputField CharRank;

   [SerializeField]
    public string playerName {  get; set; }

    }

    MyClass myObject = new MyClass();

    public string playerName;


    public string SaveToString()
    {
       myObject.playerName = playerName;
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(myObject);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        var input = gameObject.GetComponent<InputField>();
        var se = new InputField.SubmitEvent();
        //se.AddListener(SubmitName);
        //input.onEndEdit = se;

        //or simply use the line below, 
        input.onEndEdit.AddListener(SubmitName);  // This also works
    }

    private void SubmitName(string playerName)
    {
        //Debug.Log(arg0);
    Debug.Log("Entered" + playerName);

    //playerName = arg0;
    Debug.Log ("Start SubmitName!" + SaveToString());

    StartCoroutine(Post("https://mywebsite.com/api/api2.php", SaveToString()));
    }

    IEnumerator Post(string url, string bodyJsonString)
    {
        var request = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST");
        byte[] bodyRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bodyJsonString);
        request.uploadHandler = (UploadHandler) new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
        request.downloadHandler = (DownloadHandler) new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        yield return request.Send();

        Debug.Log("Status Code: " + request.responseCode);
    Debug.Log("Received: " + request.downloadHandler.text);
    Debug.Log("json string: " + SaveToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you take a moment and explain or point out what you changed, and why?

Comment: Sure sorry, so I tidied up the class and then added in the myObject.playerName = playerName; in the SaveToString

Comment: Returns `json string: {}`

Comment: You can't Serialize properties in unity just keep `[SerializeField] private string PlayerName; public string playerName { get => PlayerName; set => PlayerName = value; ` .. though actually c# naming conventions should be the other way round .. Capital name for public, minuscule for private ..

Comment: Commenting out the `{get,set}` and uncommenting the original line results in a stack overflow.

Comment: Please see my comment on your question ... Your original property is defined recursively accessing itself! Rather use the one I just posted here above ... but add the missing `}` in the end ;)

Comment: to derHugo - now I get `json string: {"PlayerName":""}` although originally threw protection error on the private setting.

Comment: Am also getting `<Post>d__6:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/IFScriptPlayerName.cs:78)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr) (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/Coroutines.cs:17)` message at bottom of debog window.